# Thread in one class on completed can it let another class know about it?

Tags: android

In android have an activity (Main Activity) that calls another class (not an activity) to do something. This class starts a thread to download data from the server. When the download is completed can I send a message to tell the main Activity class to do something else? I was looking at handlers but then the Handler needs to be defined in the same class. Is there something else that I am missing?

EDIT: 
Thanks.. But my problem is the thread is started from the other class. The scenario is I have activity that is binded to a service and is receiving messages. I send the message to a processor class that processes the message. I return with a response and send in a new request. Now for one of the message I need to get data from the server(in another class) and on downloading it I need to send the response.

Comment: Activities shouldn't actively interact with each other. You should probably use a fragment as "another class that does something".

Comment: Read about observer pattern, this is a common 'problem'

Comment: Use asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use `AsyncTask` because that's its purpose, instead of trying to do it yourself.

If `AsyncTask` is not what you're looking for (e.g. downloading takes too much time, you want to keep the thread running on the background, etc...), and all what you want is to do is GUI, you can just use `runOnUIThread` on the thread.

If previous solutions are a no-go, you can do as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private void startDownload() {
        // Start your thread passing this activity reference for example:
       YourThreadStartClass.startThreadedJob(this);
    }

    public void onDownloadFinish() {
         // Do your stuff on MainActivity after the download has finished
    }
}

public class YourThreadStartClass {
    public static void startThreadedJob(final MainActivity callback) {
        new Thread(new YourRunnable(callback)).start();
    }
}


// This is the Runnable your thread will be running
public class YourRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final MainActivity callback;

    public YourRunnable(final MainActivity activity) {
        this.callback = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         // Do your stuff on this thread and when finished:    
         this.callback.onDownloadFinish();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I've simplified a bit, but the actual right way in Java to do this would be to define an interface like

```
public interface DownloadFinishedCallback {
    void onDownloadFinish();
}
```

and make your `MainActivity` (or any other class for that matter) implement this interface, and use a `DownloadFinishedCallback` reference instead of a `MainActivity` one in `YourRunnable`.

Example with interface:

```
public interface DownloadFinishedCallback {
    void onDownloadFinish();
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DownloadFinishedCallback {

    private void startDownload() {
        // Start your thread passing this activity reference for example:
        YourThreadStartClass.startThreadedJob(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadFinish() {
        // Do your stuff on MainActivity after the download has finished
    }
}

public class YourThreadStartClass {
    public static void startThreadedJob(final DownloadFinishedCallback callback) {
        new Thread(new YourRunnable(callback));
    }
}

// This is the Runnable your thread will be running
public class YourRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final DownloadFinishedCallback callback;

    public YourRunnable(final DownloadFinishedCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your stuff on this thread and when finished:
        this.callback.onDownloadFinish();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I edit my question, but I am struck if it is interface or callback?

Comment: Doesn't matter if the thread is started from one class or the other. An interface can be a callback, they're different concepts.

Comment: @JourneyWithAndroid Also added example of how to use the interface way.

Comment: But I insist: the best way is to use `AsyncTask` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: AyyncTask sounds the best option but I had one more question as to can I implement a thread in another thread. Like in the above case if I create a thread1 to read the packet and then start another thread2 to download? Will thread 2 be part of thread 1? and then in its onPostExecute can I do the job?

Comment: There is no such thing as a thread inside a thread. Also a thread cannot be part of another thread. A thread is independent of any other thread, it executes independently of any other one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29

Comment: It worked when I used an interface and created a callback once I am done with the job. In the Async Task's onPostExecute I called the callback which notified me and that made me continue with further operations. Thank you for all the help and helping me understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `Handler` created in your UI thread and post messages to it from your worker thread.

A more general solution would be to use an event bus such as Otto or GreenRobot that can handle all the messaging in your app. I wrote [a blog post](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/event-bus-usage-on-android) about this in some detail.

Comment: I don't think that's the intended usage for `Handler`: *"There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own"*. In OP's case (and btw also in your blog post) you don't have either situation. You simply want the action done after the thread has finished. A simple callback is enough. Also in my experience using a `Handler` is significantly slower.